# Authentication issue with repo accessed from Spring Cloud Config Server hosted on GitHub

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm hosting a configuration in a repo on GitHub. If I keep the repo public all's good, but if I make it private I face:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: 
 https://github.com/my-user/my-repo:
 Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
```

the property I use to target the repo is

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/my-user/my-repo
```

What should I do to configure this properly with the private repo, thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you need to add the

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=your_github_username
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=your_github_password
```

and things should workout for you

Comment: woow, simple as that :D

Comment: Where is this in the doc.... for the life of me I couldn't find it.  Like would be greately appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: lovely ... thanks ! But yeah ... that is in fact in the docs : https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/

Comment: Hi, Can we use GitHub token instead of a password?

Comment: yes, you can use GitHub token

Answer (score 2):

[Master Slave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923710/1862590) solution works but add the token instead of the github password.

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=<your_github_username>
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=<your_github_token>
```

**Token Generation Steps:**

1. Go to github settings.
2. Then Developer Settings
3. Generate the token here.

Answer (score 1):

```
 - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_USERNAME=XXXXX
  - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXX
  - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_DEFAULT-LABEL=branchXXXXX
```

I am running this as docker, and it worked for me

for the starter's this how I am using spring cloud server as docker container

```
container_name: sccserver
ports:
  - 8080:8080
volumes:
  - /data/config-dir:/data
environment:
  - EUREKA_HOST=$DOCKERHOST
  - scc_search_paths={application}, {application}/extended-attributes, {application}/feature-flags, {application}/properties, {application}/error-codes,{application}/seed-data,{application}/globalization,{application}/json-validator-schema,{application}/seedData
  - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DOCKERHOST
  - MESSAGING_HOST=$DOCKERHOST
  - SCC_GIT_URI=https://bitbucket.com/XXXXXXX.git 
  - "JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m"
  - SCC_GIT_SKIPSSLVALIDATION=true
  - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_USERNAME=
  - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_PASSWORD=
  - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_DEFAULT-LABEL=
extra_hosts:
  - "dockerhost:$DOCKERHOST"
```

~

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem, we were working on a private project.
So I do not find very secure to provide my github username and password so :

I made repository -> public.
So it worked for me.